# How to put dots(...) if record length is too long than the column width and how to keep all columns in same size

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-6

This is a table in my view.

```
<table>
@{var counter = 1; }
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <td>
            <div class="tdWidthFixed">
            <h4 class="m0" style="color:deepskyblue">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseName)</h4>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseSubject)<br>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.institute)
                </div>
        </td>
        if (counter % 3 == 0)  //Display 3 courses at a row
    {
            @:</tr><tr> 
    }
    counter++;
}
</tr>
```

There are three lines in a one sell. But when displaying lengthy result lines breaks to new line. what i need to know is how to put dots(...) at the end of the line, if records are too long than the column width. And also how to make all the columns are in same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS for it. Try the code below.
http://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/rVRYjY

```
 <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .</h2>
 <h2>Adipiscing elit. Nam ac ultricies augue.</h2>
 <h2>Donec sed mi magna. Ut convallis</h2>

<style>
    h2 {
       display: block;
       display: -webkit-box;
       width: 400px;
       margin: 0 auto;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Note: This technique will only work in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line ellipsis on the web can be difficult. There is not a cross browser implementation in CSS to handle this. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915967/1593273) provided by [oguzhancerit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2374549/oguzhancerit) will only work on webkit browsers.  There are a couple of other solutions that may fit your needs better.

#### 1. JQuery

There are plugins available that will auto ellipsis content for you.  The plus is they are cross browser, however if there is a lot of calculations to do they can be slow.

http://pvdspek.github.io/jquery.autoellipsis/

#### 2. Server side

If your table cell is a fixed size then it is possible for you to truncate your text to a known size on the server.  An extension method will do the job.

```
public static string TruncateAtWord(this string input, int length)
{
    if (input == null || input.Length < length)
    {
        return input;
    }

    int nextSpace = input.LastIndexOf(" ", length, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    return string.Format("{0}...", input.Substring(0, (nextSpace > 0) ? nextSpace : length).Trim());
}
```

You can use this in your action method or view.

```
model.courseSubject = courseSubject.TruncateAtWord(120)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important that the div within your TD element has a width set for this to work. I applied the following 3 CSS properties and had success.

```
<td>
  <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;"> This is the long text which will be shorten and have the three dots added to the end  </div>
</td>
```